# misusing OpenMP?

Tags: c++, openmp

I have a program using OpenMP to parallelize a for-loop. Inside the loop, the threads will write to shared variable, so I need to synchronize them. However I can sometimes get either segment fault or double free or corruption error. Anyone knows what happens? Thanks and regards! Here is the code:

```
void KNNClassifier::classify_various_k(int dim, double *feature, int label, int *ks, double * errors, int nb_ks, int k_max) {   
  ANNpoint      queryPt = 0;    
  ANNidxArray   nnIdx = 0;      
  ANNdistArray  dists = 0;     

  queryPt = feature;      
  nnIdx = new ANNidx[k_max];                
  dists = new ANNdist[k_max];               

  if(strcmp(_search_neighbors, "brutal") == 0) {// search  
    _search_struct->annkSearch(queryPt, k_max,  nnIdx, dists, _eps);  
  }else if(strcmp(_search_neighbors, "kdtree") == 0) {  
    _search_struct->annkSearch(queryPt, k_max,  nnIdx, dists, _eps);  // double free or corruption
  }  

  for (int j = 0; j < nb_ks; j++)  
  {  
    scalar_t result = 0.0;  
    for (int i = 0; i < ks[j]; i++) {          
        result+=_labels[ nnIdx[i] ];  // Segmentation fault
    }  
    if (result*label<0)  
    {  
    #pragma omp critical  
    {  
      errors[j]++;  
    }  
    }  

  }  

  delete [] nnIdx;  
  delete [] dists;  

}

      void KNNClassifier::tune_complexity(int nb_examples, int dim, double **features, int *labels, int fold, char *method, int nb_examples_test, double **features_test, int *labels_test) {    
          int nb_try = (_k_max - _k_min) / scalar_t(_k_step);    
          scalar_t *error_validation = new scalar_t [nb_try];    
          int *ks = new int [nb_try];    

          for(int i=0; i < nb_try; i ++){    
            ks[i] = _k_min + _k_step * i;    
          }    

          if (strcmp(method, "ct")==0)                                                                                                                     
          {    

            train(nb_examples, dim, features, labels );// train once for all nb of nbs in ks                                                                                                

            for(int i=0; i < nb_try; i ++){    
              if (ks[i] > nb_examples){nb_try=i; break;}    
              error_validation[i] = 0;    
            }    

            int i = 0;    
      #pragma omp parallel shared(nb_examples_test, error_validation,features_test, labels_test, nb_try, ks) private(i)    
            {    
      #pragma omp for schedule(dynamic) nowait    
              for (i=0; i < nb_examples_test; i++)         
              {    
                classify_various_k(dim, features_test[i], labels_test[i], ks, error_validation, nb_try, ks[nb_try - 1]); // where error occurs    
              }    
            }    
            for (i=0; i < nb_try; i++)    
            {    
              error_validation[i]/=nb_examples_test;    
            }    
          }

          ......
     }
```

---

UPDATE:

As in my last post [double free or corruption](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2182004/double-free-or-corruption), the code runs fine with single-thread but gives runtime errors for multi-thread. The error changes from time to time. If I run it twice, one will be segfault, and the other will be double free or corruption.

Comment: What are the values of    i and    nnIdx[i] just before segfault?

Comment: i is 6. nnIdx[i] is 1708204069, which is quite wrong and way beyond what could be perceived as reasonable. Not sure why. The function that assigns values to elements of nnIdx belongs to ANN, A Library for
Approximate Nearest Neighbor Searching, see http://www.cs.umd.edu/~mount/ANN/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Let's take a look at your segmentation fault line:

```
result+=_labels[ nnIdx[i] ];
```

`result` is local -- OK.

`nnIdx` is local -- also OK.

`i` is local -- still OK.

`_labels` ... what is it?

Is it global? Did you define access to it via `#pragma shared`?

Same goes for the former:

```
_search_struct->annkSearch(queryPt, k_max,  nnIdx, dists, _eps);
```

Seems as we have here a problem that is not easily solvable -- _search_struct is not thread safe -- probably values in it are modified by threads at once. You have to have a dedicated _search_struct per-thread, probably by allocating it in classify_various_k.

The really bad news however is that ANN is probably completely non-threadable:

> The library allocates a small amount
>   of storage, which is shared by all
>   search struc- tures built during the
>   program’s lifetime. Because the data
>   is shared, it is not deallocated, even
>   when the all the individual structures
>   are deleted.

As seen above there'll always be problems with parallel data modification, because the library itself has some shared data -- hence it's not thread-safe itself :/.

Comment: _labels is a data member of class KNNClassifier. It is not explicity declared as shared foe openmp. Also if I run my progrom twice, one will be segfault, ang the other will be double free or corruption as in my last post. i.e. the error is not fixed.

Comment: _search_struct->annkSearch(queryPt, k_max,  nnIdx, dists, _eps) is to find the k_max nearest neighbor for a query point *feature among some points that have been organized in k-d tree with *_search_struct. The indices of the k-n neighbors are stored in nnIdx, and their distances to the query point in dists.

Comment: Thanks. I perhaps should not use that library if I really want to go parallel.